# How to inherit Generic Filtering in extra action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-viewsets

I want to inherit Generic Filtering include (`filterset_fields`, `search_fields`, `ordering_fields` in extra action `sold`. So how to do it, and any way better for this case?

```py
class ApartmentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartment.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ApartmentSerializer
    # Set permission for only user owner apartment can edit it.
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerApartmentOrReadOnly]
    # Add search by address, filter by district and ordering by price
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,
                       DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['district']
    search_fields = ['address', 'seller']
    ordering_fields = (
        'price',
    )

    # fill current username when create new apartment
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(seller=self.request.user)

    @action(detail=False)
    def sold(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(issold=True)
        serialize = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic View (and hence all classes that inherit from it) in DRF has a [`filter_queryset` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#filter_querysetself-queryset) which is called by the various mixins to perform filtering, so you can simply call that in your method. If you also want pagination there are the methods `paginate_queryset` and `get_paginated_response`:

```
class ApartmentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    
    @action(detail=False)
    def sold(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset.filter(issold=True))
        serialize = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```